# Shipping Program

Tags: java, output

So I seem to have put together majority of this program correctly. Ask I skim through I realized I missed something and go back and add it in. Now as I run the program for a final test I realize that it is no longer calculating the miles correctly. I input 500 for example and will get 1 in return for number of miles shipped.

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter package weight: ");
  weight = Double.parseDouble(input);

  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter approximate miles package is being shipped: ");
  miles = Integer.parseInt(input);
  miles = (miles+499)/500;

  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of units shipped: ");
  units = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

I know I am not doing the math correctly in order to find the correct amount charged per unit but what is concerning for now is the miles being shown incorrectly in my output. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What would be the result of `499/500` if you had to store the result as an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `miles` is declared as `double` (if it's not, you should declare it as `double` so you can assign it a real number). This line

```
miles = (miles+499)/500;
```

is making a integer division (`int/int = int`). To get a double, you must cast it:

```
miles = (double)(miles+499)/500;
```

or, as @Vulcan suggested

```
miles = (miles+499)/500.0; // here 500.0 is a double
```

Comment: In my case I was instructed to declare distance(miles) as an integer. Or is there a typo in my instructions?

Comment: What's the desired output (`miles` value)?

Comment: It should just output whatever amount the user input. Whether it be 500 or any other number. In my case it should be 876. The cost of shipping calculated correctly. Only missing the miles which units are being shipped.

Comment: But if it must output the same input, why do `( + 499 )/500`?

Comment: I think this is where I am confusing myself. I did remove this from my code and it looks normal now I have to figure how to get the math to work out at the end. I am unsure of how to have the program determine the applicable rate and distance to be charged.

Comment: If it's just math, first get the formula and finally implement the code.

Comment: This is where I am stuck and in return made a mess of everything else.
    charges=(miles*3.80)*units;
I am unsure how to get the program to calculate per every 500 miles. Not per mile.

Comment: `miles500 = mile / 500.0` -> `charges = (miles * 3.8 / 500.0)*units. I hope I understood the question correctly. Also, I don't see the points of making variables `int`, `charges` should be `double`. But you could also try to apply `(int) Math.round` method after calculating `charges` if you want it to be `int`.

Comment: Yes. I have something similar and had to start crunching out numbers on paper to catch myself but I am still missing something. I tried to do it differently. I did `charges=((miles*3.8)/500)*units` but the math is still wrong. Example ((550 * 3.8)/500)*1 = 4.18 and it should remain as 3.8 it should only increase the rate per every 500 miles.

Comment: Try this: `(550/500)*3.8*1`. It's hard to get what you want if you only give 1 example.

Comment: But then wouldn't I be restricted to that? I would want the user to be able to input any amount of miles and it calculate correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46613/discussion-between-christian-and-java-newb)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the data type of `miles` variable is `int`.Please change it to `double` and re-run the application.

Also as per ur comment updating the logic :

Let the input you entered is :

```
double weight = 7;   //input
double miles = 550;  //input
double unit = 2;     //input
double charges =0;   //charge of the shipment initialise with 0

charges = (3.70*miles*unit*weight)/(500*7);

System.out.println("The charges is "+charges);
```

The charges of 1 unit is $3.70 per 7 pound weight per 500 miles.

Also update the existing code :

```
 miles = Integer.parseInt(input);  //Use double as conversion
 miles = (miles+499)/500;          // remove the line
```

Comment: That's the thing, I was instructed to leave it as an int. So I am beyond confused.

Comment: As the miles result can be in double bcoz you are dividing the sum so you need to change the data type.Plz change the data type to double and go ahead.Let us knw whether it works  :)

Comment: If I were to change everything to a double i will change the result to 1.998 .. which is incorrect. The charges are not prorated so regardless of whether I input 500 or 550 it should still charge the same amount. I'm not sure if this is making sense to anyone but me. I'm terrible at explaining.

Comment: @JavaNewb Do one favour.Provide me the input of weight,miles & unit and what is ur expected ouput with the given input of this 3 [weight,miles & unit]

Comment: It should be 2 units - 7 lbs @ $3.70/unit for 550 miles. It should just equal $7.40. Instead it giving me $4070. Its multiplying miles by price per unit and then multiplying by the number of units.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46612/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-java-newb)